# CSS fixed header, scrollable body

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is not a question, actually it's a simple solution to get your table body vertically scrollable using purely css, tested only in Firefox 3.5.2, assuming correct Table DOM definitions (table, thead, tbody).

```
<style>
    .someTBODYclassName {
    height: 100px,
    overflow-x: hidden,
    overflow-y: visible
     }
 </style>
```

Of course this can be more tricky using jQuery or pure Javascript.

```
var maxHeightOfTBODY = your_calculations_here;
$("#TableId tbody.someTBODYclassName") //make it scrollable
        .css({
            "height": maxHeightOfTBODY+"px",
            "overflow-x": "hidden",
            "overflow-y": "visible",
            "width": "100%"
            });
```

Comment: would be a nice article on codeproject.com :D

Comment: Yeah, except it doesn't work in most current browsers

Comment: Plus- You didn't form your answer in the form of a question! (from FAQ; It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.)

Comment: Try this method : [click here](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) Or try QuirksMode - [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

Comment: Again it needs to be a question plus ensure that the answer works or specify which browser(s) it works in.

Comment: As I said, it's a simple solution to get your table body vertically scrollable using purely css, to Firefox 3.5. Thanks @gnarf, @CertifiedCrazy for ur information.

Comment: Please turn this into a question (soon). If it continues to collect flags it will very likely be closed.

Answer (score 5):

**What is the question? (FAQ)**

For what you need JQuery for this case?

Look at this:
http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/66-table-styling-2-fixed-header-and-highlighting/